# QLibrary Visual C++ global variables

Tags: c++, qt, dll

I use a Visual C++ DLL within a Qt project using QLibrary. Everyhing works fine for the functions, but can I also directly access global variables that are exported by the DLL? My program crashes if I try to do that, however, the resolving seems to work.

The global variables are exported just as the functions that work, with `extern "C"` and `extern __declspec (dllexport)`. Is this even possible, or do I need to write a function to return the variable first? If it is possible, could you provide an example like it is done for functions in the Qt assistant?

Answer (score 0):

You can define a function to access a global variable. The code for the shared library can be as follows :

```
int myVariable;

extern "C" Q_DECL_EXPORT int get_myVariable()
{
     return myVariable;
}
```

In your Qt application you can call the function and access the variable :

```
#include <QLibrary>

typedef int (*get_myVariable_func)();

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

    QLibrary library( "./dynamic_library" );
    library.load();
    if( !library.isLoaded() )
    {
        qDebug() << "Cannot load library.";
        return 0;
    }

    get_myVariable_func get_variable = (get_myVariable_func)library.resolve( "get_myVariable" );
    if( get_variable )
    {
        int var= get_variable();

        qDebug() << "my variable = " << var;

    }

    return a.exec();
}
```

Comment: Thanks Nejat, I'm sure your answer will help others. Unfortunately, in may case, the variables of the DLL are not class members but global, I edited my question to make that clearer.

Comment: I asked if it is possible to directly access them. According to your post I guess the answer is no then, I need to modify the DLL and put them into a function.